# how can I accomplish interior mutability(?) in a struct I am moving to another thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a structure that uses a limited form of dynamic programming.  It maintains a cache of previously computed results to speed up later computations.  I am currently storing it in a `RefCell`.  I recently started experimenting with multiple threads.  Unfortunately I can not seem to `Send` `clone()`s of this data structure into a `thread::spawn()`

```
error[E0277]: `RefCell<DualKeyHashMap<search_context::CostKey, PlanCostLog>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/parallel_astar.rs:30:9
    |
30  |         std::thread::spawn(move || {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `RefCell<DualKeyHashMap<search_context::CostKey, PlanCostLog>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    | 
   ::: /home/thoth/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:624:8
    |
624 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ---- required by this bound in `spawn`
    |
    = help: within `SearchContext`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `RefCell<DualKeyHashMap<search_context::CostKey, PlanCostLog>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `SearchContext`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&SearchContext`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/parallel_astar.rs:30:28: 42:10]`
```

Jmb's fix worked fine for my minimal example, but not on the full code, so I had to complicate the example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::thread;

//#[derive(Clone)]
struct Inner {
    pub val: i32,
}

//#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bacon {
    count: RefCell<Inner>,
}

impl Bacon {
    fn incr(&self) {
        self.count.borrow_mut().val += 1;
    }

    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.count.borrow().val
    }
}

fn go(bacon: &Bacon) {
    let handles = (0..10)
        .map(move |_| {
            let b2 = bacon.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                b2.incr();
                println!("{}", b2.get())
            })
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bacon = Bacon {
        count: RefCell::new(Inner{val:0}),
    };
    go(&bacon);
}
```

I can work around it by cloning the pieces of the `SearchContext` and building a new one inside the thread.  One oddity is that I can `clone()` the field that is a `RefCell`, and `move` that into the thread to construct a new object (even though it is not necessary in my context).

Since some of the comments mention accessing the RefCell from multiple threads:  I do not want to access the RefCell from multiple threads. That is why I am cloning and moving the data structure.  Every thread should get its own indepent copy of `Bacon` (or `SearchContext`)

Comment: You need to replace `RefCell` with `Mutex` if you want it to be accessible from multiple threads.

Comment: Or make the bacon a plain struct and put it in a mutex, instead of making the struct itself "smart".

Comment: @jmb your playground is missing the `main` function which is the problematic one (as it tries to capture a refcell).

Comment: "One oddity is that I can clone() the field that is a RefCell, and move that into the thread to construct a new object (even though it is not necessary in my context)." that's not odd at all: `RefCell` is `Send` so you can *move* a refcell between threads, but it's not `Sync` so you can't *share* it: refcells are non-thread-safe `Mutex`s, so different threads manipulating the same refcell would be broken. But there is no relation between copies of a RefCell (it's not an `Rc`/`Arc`) so the clone and original don't interact.

Comment: Given your last edit, just add `move` to the closure in your call to `spawn`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a3621833ebbb20702335ed6f94d4e9f).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the real problem is that the `Bacon` does not implement `Clone`.

The error message the compiler gives does not point at this problem, so it took me a while to check for it.  I'm not sure why it didn't give an error about the call to `bacon.clone()` .  Maybe the one error short-circuited error checking of the rest of the closure.

Comment: `bacon` is a shared reference, and all shared references implement `Clone`, so `let b2 = bacon.clone();` is a perfectly valid line of code with the same meaning as `let b2 = bacon;` (i.e., it clones the reference, not the `Bacon`). Implementing `Clone` for `Bacon` changes the method resolution order so that it does what you wanted. In principle the compiler could warn about the unnecessary `clone`, and I think there is an issue for doing just that.